# Compiling in Qt Creator on OS X: "dyld: Library not loaded"

Tags: qt, dyld

I've searched around and can't find an answer to this. I'm trying to compile some examples in Qt Creator (Qt 5.0.1) on Mac OS X Lion, and it keeps giving me errors. Here's the full error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /Users/bld.qt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/DQTC-RELEASE5LGPL-OSX106/______________________________PADDING______________________________/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWidgets
Referenced from: /Users/<bleh>/Qt5.0.1/5.0.1/clang_64/examples/widgets/widgets/codeeditor-build-Desktop_Qt_5_0_1_clang_64bit-Debug/codeeditor.app/Contents/MacOS/codeeditor
Reason: image not found
```

Anyone know any fixes?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it can't find the QtWidgets library. Add this to your .pro file

> qt += widgets

Based on [the transition from Qt 4 to 5](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Transition_from_Qt_4.x_to_Qt5) where QtWidgets are a Separate Module

Comment: I have the same problem, and in my .pro file I already have that line.

Comment: @Pietro, if you're still having problems, check your Qt paths.